# Index of essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on a punctured disk $\Delta^*$ with essential singularity at puncture. Furthermore suppose that it has no zeroes on $\Delta^*$.

**Question**: Does this integral have to be zero?
$$\int_{C} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz$$
$C$ is a contour around the puncture.

**Comment 1** More geometrically you can think about this number as follows. $f: \mathbb{C}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$. This integral is degree of $f$ (how it acts on first homologies). Also it may be referred as index of vector field.

**Comment 2** For the most obvious example $f(z) = e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ this number is zero.

Comment: Hint: it can be expanded as a Laurent series on this set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Compute the integral for $f(z)=ze^{1/z}$. The answer is nonzero.